# How to create Start and End $Nodes to make the KML code below?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3, nodes, kml

I would like to show on google maps where my first latlng from MySql database is and show the last know marker from MySql latlng. I have a route of markers which is fine, but would just like to know how to show my start and end in different icon style like the kml code below and image but in $nodes, please help?

```
<Style id="startPlacemark">
<IconStyle>
<color>ffffffff</color>
<Icon>
<href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="finishPlacemark">
<IconStyle>
<color>ffffffff</color>
<Icon>
<href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-stars.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#</styleUrl>
    <name>2015-07-22T10:07:34</name>
    <description>Sim - Battery: Unknown</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.706527,51.582089</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#</styleUrl>
    <name>2015-07-22T10:44:13</name>
    <description>Sim - Battery: Unknown</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.7066757,51.582109</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#finishPlacemark</styleUrl>
    <name>2015-10-21T12:23:54</name>
    <description>Sim - Battery: 100%</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-0.7066785,51.58289</coordinates>
    </Point>    
</Placemark>
```

---

[image: Maps of (white)start and (yellow)finish]

Comment: Are you asking how to change the marker icons for the results from the directions service when you provide the request information from mySql?  What do KML icons have to do with that? (or for that matter $Node).  What does your existing Google Maps Javascript API v3 code look like?  The posted KML doesn't include the actual icon definitions, and we can't get those from a picture.

Comment: Sorry not to change the Marker at all, but to start with a white Marker for this example or any Marker different from the ones showing the route(red) when the route come to a finish to show only the Yellow one, The KML code is to show at little of how this looks in KML but I dont know how this was achieve, Hence my question.

Comment: Here the Google link for it : https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml?hl=en but dont help with start and end Markers.

Comment: Please edit your question to address comments. Posting code/XML/KML in the comments is not particularly useful, it is difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the edit to the KML is made, any ideas about this?